# Perl - Package/Module Issues

Tags: perl, perl-module

From everything I've read on using Perl modules, the basic usage is:

- Module file with `.pm` extension, which includes the statement `package <name>`, where `<name>` is the filename of the module without the extension.
- Code file that uses module contains the statement `use <name>;`.

The application I'm coding has one main code script which uses about 5 modules. I had forgotten to include the `package <name>` statement in the modules, but my code still ran just fine with the `use <name>` statement. I started receiving `Undefined subroutine` errors with one of the modules, so I added the package statement to each of the modules. Now the rest of those modules **stopped** working. What gives?

*Example:*

mainapp.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use UtyDate;
my $rowDate = CurrentDate("YYYYMMDD");
```

UtyDate.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package UtyDate;
sub CurrentDate
{
    #logic
}
return 1;
```

When I run the above code, I get the error `Undefined subroutine &main::CurrentDate called at...`. However, if I remove the `package UtyDate;` line from UtyDate.pm, I get no error. This situation exists for several but not all of my modules.

There's obviously a lot more code I'm not showing, but I'm confused how any of the code I'm not showing could affect the package/use constructs I've shown here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use a module, the code in the module is run at compile time.  Then import is called on the package name for the module.  So, `use Foo;` is the same as `BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import; }`

Your code worked without the `package` declarations because all the code was executed under the package `main`, which is used by the main application code.

When you added the `package` declarations it stopped working, because the subroutines you defined are no longer being defined in `main`, but in `UtyDate`.

You can either access the subroutines by using a fully qualified name `UtyDate::CurrentDate();` or by importing the subroutines into the current name space when you `use` the module.

UtyDate.pm

```
package UtyDate;
use strict;
use warnings; 

use Exporter 'import';

# Export these symbols by default.  Should be empty!    
our @EXPORT = ();

# List of symbols to export.  Put whatever you want available here.
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( CurrentDate  AnotherSub ThisOneToo );

sub CurrentDate {
    return 'blah';
}

sub AnotherSub { return 'foo'; }
```

Main program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

use UtyDate 'CurrentDate';

# CurrentDate is imported and usable.    
print CurrentDate(), " CurrentDate worked\n";

# AnotherSub is not
eval {  AnotherSub() } or print "AnotherSub didn't work: $@\n";

# But you can still access it by its fully qualified name
print UtyDate::AnotherSub(), " UtyDate::AnotherSub works though\n";
```

See [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) docs for more info.

Comment: OP should read `perlmod` (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlmod) first as a prerequisite for understanding what goes on in `Exporter`.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I had seen Exporter used in some of the examples I saw, but not all, so I thought it was unrelated.

I'll take a look at the doc too mobrule, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the exporter perl header code.  You will need to add something like the following to the top of your pm file below the package statement:

```
package UtyDate;
BEGIN {
  use Exporter ();
  use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT);
  $VERSION = "1.0.0";
  @ISA = qw(Exporter);
  @EXPORT = qw( &CurrentDate );
}
```

See this link: http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#DESCRIPTION

Comment: Edit according to http://p3rl.org/Exporter#Good_Practices or better use [Sub::Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Sub::Exporter) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Gray's suggestion, you can do this:

```
use UtyDate;
UtyDate::CurrentDate(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the exporter, as Gray points out, you could (UGLY, but works) also call the functions with the module name ..

You functiond/procedures don't work since they are now in a differen namespace (defined by the module name)

```
use UtyDate;

UtyDate::CurrentDate(  )
```

Comment: That's not ugly; that's the standard way to call functions that aren't written in an OO-style.

Comment: The namespace is defined by the `package` call, not the name of the module. It is just a convention (though a good one) that the package name and the module name are the same.

Comment: @Ether: being standard is not the same as 'not ugly', I fear. Besides, I meant 'ugly' as compared to Gray's 'solution', that required much less change to the code already written ('much change' is what I consider 'ugly' as in: change begets bugs. YMMV